# Which one is better: "sunt aequivalentes" or "aequivalent"?

Tags: word-comparison, contemporary-latin, new-latin, participle, mathematics

If I want to say that two things are equivalent in Latin, I can imagine two ways using essentially the same word:

1. *X et Y sunt aequivalentes.*
2. *X et Y aequivalent.*

Googling for the first option (without *X et Y*) produces numerous Latin texts with the phrase.
Both intuition and [L&S](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=aequivaleo&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) suggest that *aequivalere* is a verb that should have the same effect as the first option.

Option 1 has the benefit of matching the structure used in many other languages.
However, using *esse* with a present participle (a present active periphrasis) looks a bit weird to me.

The phrase is particularly common in mathematics, but [not confined to that one field](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/1/79).
Here is an example sentence: "The following statements are equivalent."
This sentence would then be followed by a list of statements.

Is there a difference between 1 and 2?
Are there cases where one should be used instead of the other?
Did the participle *aequivalens* get a meaning separate from its parent verb, so that it should not really be treated as its form?
Is either option more idiomatic or otherwise better in your opinion?
(If so, why?)

I am interested in using the phrase in today's world, but insights from any era are welcome.

Comment: How is this question really different from [this one](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/2978/can-esse-be-used-with-a-present-participle), and per that question, are you looking at Classical, endorsed Latin, the sheer possibility of it, or developments from Late, Medieval, and post-Medieval Latin?

Comment: Can you also specify what you want to say in English?

Comment: @C.M.Weimer I added a remark about the eras and an example sentence. I can give an extended example if needed. I'm interested in this one case specifically, so it could be different from the general case. Perhaps one can read this question as "Did the participle *aequivalens* lose its verbal meaning?". But if you think (or anyone thinks) this question is fully answered by the older one, I have nothing against votes to close as duplicate.

Comment: Have you not thought of using _tantusdem_? It seems to have exactly the quality that you are looking for.

Comment: A quick google has found Quint. Inst. I, 5: _idem significant et tantundem valent_.

Comment: @TomCotton Good finds, thanks! I had not heard of *tantusdem* before. I think it will help most modern mathematical readers if I use a phrase etymologically related to "equivalent", but *tantusdem* is indeed a good option to keep in mind.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta The word is rare enough that you should be able to do as you please. My only suggestion is to find what other mathematicians writing in Latin use and go with that.

Comment: I don't think this question is a duplicate of [the one about _esse_ + pres. partic.](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/2978/can-esse-be-used-with-a-present-participle). This one is more specific, seeking an idiom for logic or mathematics.