# What combinations of tenses appear in periphrasis?

Tags: verbs, conjugation, participle, perfect-tense

Periphrastic verb forms, specifically a participle plus an auxiliary verb, are very common in English ("I am writing now"). They also appear in Latin and Ancient Greek and a number of Romance languages.

The types I'm most familiar with in Latin are the passives of the perfect system, and the gerundive of obligation.

> Perfect passive participle + present = perfect passive
>   Perfect passive participle + imperfect = pluperfect passive
>   Perfect passive participle + future = future perfect passive
>   Future passive participle + present = future passive

[This question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/5315/which-grammatical-format-is-the-double-perfect-system-as-found-in-the-vulgate) indicates that you can also find perfect passive participle + perfect, to emphasize that an action is complete.

Are there any other attested combinations? For example, do we ever see a present participle combined with an auxiliary?

Comment: I think you mean future *active* participle? // I believe forms like *daturus erat* are possible. There is also the subjunctive, *daturus sit*. // Present participles can be used with auxiliaries when the participle is felt to be like an adjective, I believe. // *Habere* + p.p.p. is also possible, although, in classical Latin, most would not call it an actual periphrastic tense, but rather a special construction.

Comment: @Cerberus Ah, no, I'm thinking of *Carthago delenda est* with the passive. Though the rest of those would make a good answer!

Comment: Ah, I would call that a grundive!

Comment: @Cerberus True; I was taught that the gerundive was also effectively a passive participle, so the gerundive of obligation construction was a form of periphrastic. Do you think it belongs with the others?

Comment: Hmm perhaps it depends on one's definition of periphrasis? But it is at least a very similar construction, so why not!

Comment: As brianpck wrote in his comment on this question (https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/2978/can-esse-be-used-with-a-present-participle/2979), the Vulgate is full of examples of active present participle + esse, likely influenced by Greek.